# Differences in formatting using Intl.DateTimeFormat when including the script name

Tags: javascript, datetime-format, intl

Wonder if anyone knows why when using Intl.DateTimeFormat to create a formatter using 'en-GB' as the locale will give a different output to using 'en-Latn-GB' but using 'zh-HK' and 'zh-Hant-HK' will give the same result.

See example below and JSFiddle

```js
const date = new Date(Date.parse('2020-12-20T03:23:16'));


// Specify default date formatting for language (locale)
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date));
// expected output: "20/12/2020"
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-Latn-GB').format(date));
// expected output: "20/12/2020"

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('zh-HK').format(date));
// expected output: "20/12/2020"
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('zh-Hant-HK').format(date));
// expected output: "20/12/2020"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aqn0e4tp/

The background to why we end up with 'en-Latn-GB' is for various reason we originally created a Intl.Locale for 'en-GB' and then called Locale.maximize() to default in some properties then after doing that using Locale.baseName as the locale when creating a formatter. In this situation Locale.baseName includes the script 'Latn'.

We can work around that issue but I am curious to know why there should be a difference.

Comment: I'd try running [`Intl.DateTimeFormat.supportedLocalesOf(locales, options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/supportedLocalesOf) to make sure 'en-Latn-GB' is supported by the browser. You might also try playing around with the `localeMatcher` option to see if changing it to "lookup" helps.

Comment: Actually, run this in your browser: `console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(new Intl.Locale('en-Latn-GB'), { localeMatcher: 'lookup' }).resolvedOptions());` and see what's in the `locale` property.

Comment: Yeah I sort of figured it defaulted back to effectively 'en-US' but that doesn't seem right to me. 
We start with asking the browser to create a locale for 'en-GB' which looks good then ask it to fill in the defaults, it doesn't seem right to me for it to effectively dump 'GB' - and it is not doing that in zh-Hant-HK.
At the moment what we do is create the locale, maximize it, then check if the script is 'Latn' and if so go back and recreate the locale using only the language and region codes.
Which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You're absolutely right that it doesn't make sense. My browser reports that 'en-Latn-GB' is a supported locale for `DateTimeFormat`, so it shouldn't be falling back to the browser's default locale. That is, after all, what `supportedLocalesOf` is supposed to do: return a list of the locales given that are supported by `DateTimeFormat` without falling back to the default. Interestingly, through some totally non-scientific sampling, it seems to only happen for `en` locales... \*Sigh\* This is why we can't have nice things. Sorry I couldn't provide an answer, only commiserate.